# Water dripping out from freezer compartment onto floor. What do?

Tags: appliances

Once every few days, a puddle forms in front of my Kitchenaid KSR series refrigerator.  Kitchenaid support has been completely useless in resolving this issue, other than to say reports of this condition are "rare".

It appears to be the periodic defrost.  The tray below the fridge remains dry.
Ice builds up on the freezer floor by layer until the most recent defrost operation flows over onto the  floor.  Here with green food coloring for the picture:

[image: Kitchenaid Refrigerator Drip]

I have a second fridge in a rental unit, where the water instead ends up on the top shelf of the refrigerator.

How can I clean what appears to be blockages in the drain lines leading from freezer to the under fridge drying tray?  What causes these tubes to clog?

Fridge temperature does not appear to be the direct problem:
[image: Kitchenaid KSR Series Fridge Humidity and Temperature Graph. Single Compresor.]

Answer (score 2):

Mm the drain is a simple hole made by a piece of formed plastic, pull the drawer out pour some warm water wipe up and repeat not boiling water that will deform the plastic after a few times if the plug doesn’t break loose a small screwdriver may be needed to push the plug out once you have the hole cleared and the bottom wiped up it should start cycling normally. I have seen a small chunk of food or plastic cause this problem, the plug needs to be cleared and the majority of the water in the bottom cleaned up and it will normally work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OP here:

I was unable to clear this from the inside, or even reach the top of the drain from the inside of the freezer, as it's buried behind sheet metal.

Eventually I felt underneath, and discovered a trap.  Yes, the drain tube has a P shaped bend just like a sink trap. 
An inexpensive flexible plastic drain clearing tool did the trick, able to follow the sharp bends.  Out came a wad of soaking wet dust that looked like dryer lint.

[image]